# автодополение в django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Подскажите есть ли какая то библиотека для авто дополнения в django-forms?
Нашел в просторах интернета библиотеку *django-autocomplete-light* но в документации не понял как она применяется.  Есть такая модель:

```
class PrinterSchedule(Schedule):
    printer = models.ForeignKey(Printer, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Принтер")
    status = models.ForeignKey(PrinterStatus, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Статус")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Room, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Место расположение")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Журнал принтера"
        verbose_name_plural = "Журналы принтеров"

    @staticmethod
    def get_absolute_url():
        return reverse('printerScheduleList')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.apper
```

Есть класс с формой:

```
class PrinterScheduleCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PrinterSchedul
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'apper': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'printer':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'location': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date': forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
```

Необходимо, что бы `'printer':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})` можно был автодополнения при вводе символов.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй `django_select2` - https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

там есть функционал, который тебе нужен. В твоем случае можно использовать будет `Select2Widget`

```
    widgets = {
        ...
        'printer':Select2Widget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать гораздо проще без установки библиотек

К примеру так:

```
     <form action="" method="POST">
            {{form.as_p}}
            {% csrf_token %}
    
            <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
        </form>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_printer).select2();
    });
        </script>
```

Посмотрите видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VYx-cNF1lU
https://github.com/akjasim/cb_dj_select2

Comment: смысл у библиотек в том, что они автоматически будут подкидывать данные из связанной модели + можно настроить различные зависимости. Например при заполненном поле А, выдаем данные из одного поля модели, при заполненном поле Б - данные из второго поля модели. Т.е. они позволяют максимально подробно передать тот контекст который тебе нужен

Comment: Andrey Maslov, вы видимо на "своей волне". Я предложил один из вариантов решения вопроса.
Мой ответ не содержит ни слова про "смысл у библиотек"